# How can we use HTTP and HTTPS both ATS (App Transport Security) in One Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios9, app-transport-security

> Apple announced “App Transport Security” for iOS 9 and OSX 10.11 El Capitan. The “[What’s New in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html)” guide for iOS 9 explains:
>
> App Transport Security (ATS) lets an app add a declaration to its
> Info.plist file that specifies the domains with which it needs secure
> communication. ATS prevents accidental disclosure, provides secure
> default behavior, and is easy to adopt. You should adopt ATS as soon
> as possible, regardless of whether you’re creating a new app or
> updating an existing one.

If we want to remove or disable the ATS means we want to use only HTTP then we are doing entry in the `.plist` file like as :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

And if our domain is in HTTPS we are doing entry in `.plist` file like as :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

**Issue is :**

If my app is working on the web-services like as HTTP only. And I want to use the HTTPS domains like as google map or Facebook login etc. Or anything like one web-service is for the HTTPS domain.

Then **How we can combine both the things in the `.plist` file?**

Comment: So, you want to use HTTPS only for specific domains, and HTTP for everything else?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Yes both case. Vise versa.

Comment: Simply add the exception for the domain where you want https and don't include the `NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` key

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. Can you describe more in the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your app *(a third-party web browser, for instance)* needs to load arbitrary content, Apple provides a way to disable ATS altogether, but I suspect it’s wise for you to use this capability sparingly:

Disabling [ATS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html) entirely. Simply include the following in your **Info.plist** file then after you can use `HTTP` and `HTTPS` in One Application

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
      <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can we upload our App to the App Store after disabling ATS entirely?