# Setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in iOS 9 - Will Apple reject the app?

Tags: ios, ios9, info.plist

I suddenly get a message on `iOS 9` :

> The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security
>   policy requires the use of a secure connection

[**Searched**](http://lostincompilation.co/2015/09/ios9-the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requires-the-use-of-a-secure-connection/) a bit and found that setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to YES fixes this which actually works.
However I also found that [**Apple may reject the App**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9/30732693#30732693) for this. 
Though stated in [**App Transport Security Technote**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html)

> NSAllowsArbitraryLoads
>
> A Boolean value used to disable App Transport Security for any domains not listed in the NSExceptionDomains dictionary. Listed
>   domains use the settings specified for that domain.

But since this is the only solution working right now and also Apple **may or may not** reject the App, just wanted to confirm before publishing.

**Update**: Apple passed the review and my app is live now with this setting :)

Comment: Apple has given solution for this. I don't think so apple will reject the app. Because if we want to use the HTTP and HTTPS both in same application then this is only a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774138/how-can-we-use-http-and-https-both-ats-app-transport-security-in-one-applicati

Comment: I submit my new version app a week ago with this key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `YES`, and  have passed app review process

Comment: @Leo : Good to know that :)

Comment: @AshishKakkad : Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: @Leo Thanks. Let me know after successful release of your app. I have similar question.

Comment: @Nitish Welcome brother.

Comment: @AshishKakkad It has successful released

Comment: Exactly. This will be the first reference to this problem I have seen so far :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update:**

**Apple announced that iOS apps have until January 1, 2017, to enable App Transport Security**.

So,if you plan submit app to app store **after 2017,please turn on ATS**.

Also,see this [link](https://www.cnet.com/news/ios-apps-will-require-secure-https-connections-by-2017/)

====== Old answer=====

My experience:

I submit my app at **9/17/2015**, and have passed the app store review process and successfully released the app.

Here is the info.plist screenshot of my app. 
[image]

**So,I do not think apple will reject the app for this reason for now**

**Update:**

My new app **passed** apple review process at **10/30/2015** with this key set to YES.

Comment: It seems quite bizarre that Apple introduced this security feature, but make it trivial to get around it ??

Comment: Here's exactly how to address the issue for anyone googling here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32038743/294884

Comment: Maybe not now, but in the upcoming iterations of iOS, apple may start rejecting such apps.

Comment: My App with this setting got live :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. My new app also passed the review process today

Comment: From what i understand, this is about allowing an app to opt-in on important domains/subdomains, so if a weaker security layer is noticed, iOS can block the connection. This would allow an app developer to say "really don't allow MITM attacks on foo.com"

Answer (score 1):

Wasted a considerable amount of time (⏱ == ) because of this.  Testing new NSURL... code failed with some users, worked with others. Had no idea why.  Then stumbled on the log output which I normally don't watch (who really sees logs on an iPhone, seriously...) and there was this warning.

That was a rather nasty trick Apple... wasted time in debugging, wasted time in frustrating users, losing credibility in having software that "works".   Broken spokes due to Apple's stick shoved in there. Going to have to toss Apple under the bus  with my testers on this one.

Ref: 
NSAppTransportSecurity : NSAllowsArbitraryLoads
NSAppTransportSecurity : NSExceptionDomains

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, the whole error text is:  App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.